# kernel panic message during installing android-x86 in virtualbox

Tags: android-x86, virtualbox

I was trying to install android-x86 inside my virtualbox last evening. But I wasn't able to make it right. I'm getting a 'kernel panic' message. How do I overcome it? The following is a snapshot of what I got out of my installation attempt.

[image: kernel panic message - image]